# Primefaces growl with unhandled FacesMessages

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I encounter a small problem with rendering a face messages. I am using primefaces 6 and Java8.

Using the tag p:growl I want to display a message to the user. All other part of the page is working except this button. The message I have is the following :

`There are some unhandled FacesMessages, this means not every FacesMessage had a chance to be rendered.
These unhandled FacesMessages are: 
-  Rechargez la page`

I think it is because I have not well understand how to find the id `growl` in the page (I though @(growl) will do the job but I think it failed)

```js
 public void suppressEnquete(int idEnquete) {
 boolean success = StatFilterDao.suppressEnqueteById(idEnquete);
 
 FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
 if (!success) context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Something went wrong",  "Please try again later") );
 else context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Enquête supprimé",  " Rechargez la page") );
}
```

```html
<h:form>
<p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" sticky="true" /> 

 <p:dataTable var="formulaire" value="#{statFilter.formulaireComplete}"
  widgetVar="formulairesTable"
  emptyMessage="Aucun formulaire trouvé avec ces critères"
  filteredValue="#{statFilter.formulaireFiltre}">
  
  <f:facet name="header">
   <p:outputPanel>
    <h:outputText value="Recherche dans tous les formulaires : " />
    <p:inputText id="globalFilter" onkeyup="PF('formulairesTable').filter()"
     style="width:150px" placeholder="Entrez un mot clef"> <p:ajax event="change" update="average" /></p:inputText>
     
   </p:outputPanel>
  </f:facet>
...
  <p:column headerText="Options" escape="false" >
   <p:commandButton value="Supprimer" actionListener="#{statFilter.suppressEnquete(formulaire.idEnquete)}" icon="fa fa-remove" update="@(growl)" /> 
  </p:column>
 </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
```

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Try update="@id(growl)" or just update="growl"

Comment: Or add an autoupdate to the growl

Comment: @Melloware, I tried but it did not work...
Kukeltje It works ! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You should put p:growl at the end of your xthml.
2. `update="@(growl)"` is nonsense. Do `<p:growl autoUpdate="true" ...` instead.